# My canvas in my code is only displaying after my for loop. I am after an animation effect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am learning javascript OOP and have decided to implement Langstons ant. I am having trouble with the html5 canvas though. When I run this my debugging alerts in Ant.js pop up as expected but only after they have all done does the canvas appear in my browser (chrome). It then looks like the state that it should be at the end of the loop.
Why is this?
Thanks in advance..

Here is my code;

langstonsAnt.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Langstons Ant</title>
<script defer src="antGame.js"></script>
<script src="Ant.js"></script>
<script src="AntWorld.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="antboard" width="700" height="700" style="border: 5px solid black; background-size: 100%;">
    Canvas not supported
</canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

antGame.js

```
let c = document.getElementById("antboard");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
startGame(ctx);

function startGame(ctx)
{
    for (let x=0; x<100; x++)
    {
        for (let y=0; y<100; y++)
        {
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fillRect(7 * x, 7 * y, 7, 7);
        }
    }
}

// create antWorld board
let world = new AntWorld(100, ctx);

// create the ant
let ant = new Ant(world.board);

// place the ant on the board
world.setAntPos(ant.getAntX(), ant.getAntY());


// THIS IS THE LOOP I AM REFERRING THAT CALLS THE ALERTS.
for (let i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    ant.moveForward();
    world.setAntPos(ant.getAntX(),ant.getAntY());
    //sleep(100);
}

function sleep(milliseconds) {
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    for (let i=0; i<1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Ant.js

```
class Ant
{
    constructor(board)
    {
        this.board = board;
        this.antX = 50;
        this.antY = 35;
        this.NORTH = 0;
        this.EAST = 1;
        this.SOUTH = 2;
        this.WEST = 3;
        this.antDirection = this.NORTH;
    }

    getAntX()
    {
        return this.antX;
    }

    getAntY()
    {
        return this.antY;
    }

    moveForward()
    {
        switch (this.antDirection)
        {

            case this.NORTH:
                // change direction and colour the square based on rules
                if (this.board[this.antY][this.antX] === 0) // if sqr is white
                {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 1;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.WEST;
                } else { // if sqr is black
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 0;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.EAST;
                }
                // move ant forward
                this.antY--;
                break;
            case this.SOUTH:
                // then colour the new square based on rules
                if (this.board[this.antY][this.antX] === 0)
                {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 1;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.EAST;
                } else {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 0;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.WEST;
                }
                // move ant forward
                this.antY++;
                break;
            case this.EAST:
                // then colour the new square based on rules
                if (this.board[this.antY][this.antX] === 0)
                {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 1;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.NORTH;
                } else {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 0;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.SOUTH;
                }
                // move ant forward
                this.antX++;
                break;
            case this.WEST:
                // then colour the new square based on rules
                if (this.board[this.antY][this.antX] === 0)
                {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 1;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.SOUTH;
                } else {
                    this.board[this.antY][this.antX] = 0;
                    alert('About to fillRect');
                    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
                    ctx.fillRect(7 * this.antX, 7 * this.antY, 7, 7);
                    this.antDirection = this.NORTH;
                }
                // move ant forward
                this.antX--;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

AntWorld.js

```
class AntWorld
{
    constructor(size)
    {
        this.board = Array(size).fill(0).map(()=>Array(size).fill(0));
    }

    setAntPos(antX, antY)
    {
        this.board[antY][antX] = 1;
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillRect(7 * antX, 7 * antY, 7, 7);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do (after removing the alerts and uncommenting `sleep()`) is an [busy sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting). That means that in your sleep routine Javascript is kept busy. There's no time to do anything else, like rendering the canvas, because it is looping.

What you need to use is system events to perform the next action. Normally that would be a keypress by the user or the timer.

So, let's recode this bit of code, using the timer:

```
for (let i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    ant.moveForward();
    world.setAntPos(ant.getAntX(),ant.getAntY());
    sleep(100);
}
```

With the timer that would become:

```
function moveTheAnt()
{
    ant.moveForward();
    world.setAntPos(ant.getAntX(),ant.getAntY());
    stepCount++;
    if (stepCount > 16) clearInterval(stepTimer);
}

let stepCount = 0;
let stepTimer = setInterval(moveTheAnt, 100);
```

You can see it in action here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/nx7L0ue4/6)

For more information on the Javascript timer see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

For information on events in general see: https://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_events.asp

Both links are just examples, there might be better tutorials out there.

Comment: Will `clearTimeout()` clear a `setInterval()` handle?

Comment: @canon Yes, it will, but I'll correct it. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout "It's worth noting that the pool of IDs used by setTimeout() and setInterval() are shared, which means you can technically use clearTimeout() and clearInterval() interchangeably. However, for clarity, you should avoid doing so."

Comment: Thanks. It's working now. That is perfect. It is the system events thing I needed to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do animation in JavaScript in the browser you should really be using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and structure your code appropriately.

that said, if you just want to hack away you can use async/await in your loop. First we need a function that will wait a while

```
function sleep(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Then we need to put the loop in an `async` function and call `sleep` with the `await` keyword.

```
async function loop() {
  for (let i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
      ant.moveForward();
      world.setAntPos(ant.getAntX(),ant.getAntY());
      await sleep(100);  // pause 100 milliseconds
  }
}
loop();
```

Here's an example

```js
function sleep(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function loop() {
  for (let i=0; i<16; i++)
  {
      console.log(i);
      await sleep(1000);  // pause 1000 milliseconds
  }
}
loop();
```

For more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely use this approach if my needs get more extensive. I do need to learn about the correct animation process for future projects.